# Azure Container App "InvalidParameterValueInContainerTemplate" Custom Vnet

Tags: azure, vnet, azure-container-apps

I'm trying to deploy a quickstart image to my azure container environment and am receiving the following error;

```
The following field(s) are either invalid or missing. Field 
'template.containers.simple-hello-world-container-image' is invalid with 
details: 'Invalid Value: "mcr.microsoft.com/k8se/quickstart:latest": Get 
"https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/:EOF';
```

My environment has a workflow profile, is linked to a custom vnet (with custom DNS) and is internal facing.

If I create this without a custom vnet, I don't have any problems.

It seems like I'm getting blocked outbound. Do I need any additional config for the custom vnet or custom dns?

Comment: This specifically concerns MCR (container registry). in your custom vnet, there are some settings you check such as verifying that your container instance can resolve external hostnames (DNS related issue). Or, if you have any NSG on your VNet, check if its blocking the outbound connection from your container instance. You can also share us a architecture diagram it would be easier to troubleshoot (showing what you have inside the VNet etc.). Lastly, also mention if you have a Private endpoint or link. Use nslookup, curl from within an instance to diagnose DNS and connectivity issues.

Comment: Hey, thanks for coming back to me. Its a container app not a container instance just for clarification. As for architecture, we have a traditional hub and spoke, we're routing all traffic through our central custom DNS and out through our firewall.

Answer (score 0):

We got there - turns out this error was from a health probe unable to access to the container registry.

Azure was essentially being blocked by the firewall - follow the docs kids!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking?tabs=azure-cli